# how to Visual studio 2010 integrated shell with sapphiresteel amethyst

Tags: actionscript-3, visual-studio-2010

I read in one of the reviews that you could use SapphireSteel Amethyst
plugin with the  VS express editions using the VS Integrated Shell.I have never personally used the the VS Shell integration so does snyone  know how to go about doing this?

Comment: The Express edition is *not* the same as the Shell edition.  Express doesn't support add-ons.  It is up to the vendor to integrate their product with it.  They don't seem to have one for the 2010 shell yet.

Answer (score 0):

Amethyst is a VS package which (due to built-in restrictions of VS Express, cannot be installed into VS Express). It can be installed into the VS Shell, however.

Please see here: http://www.sapphiresteel.com/Products/Ruby-In-Steel/FAQ/installation/article/can-i-install-ruby-in-steel-or